# Scale large images using Java and AsyncScalr

Tags: java, image, image-processing, image-scaling, imgscalr

I'm using AsyncScalr in a Servlet to scale down some large images (~ 10-15 MegaBytes), the actual resizing process takes about 40ms which is not much. The overkill comes from Reading the Image from Local Storage as a BufferedImage.
so the times are mostly like :

read the image file : 1630ms !!
resizing the image : 41ms
writing the image : 40ms

below is the code that I'm using, is there any more optimal way to do this?

```
        final FileImageInputStream fileImageInputStream = new FileImageInputStream(file);
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(fileImageInputStream);

        // resize file
        Future<BufferedImage> result = AsyncScalr.resize(bufferedImage, Method.SPEED, width, OP_ANTIALIAS, OP_BRIGHTER);
        try {
            bufferedImage = result.get();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Write the image
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, imageOutput, outputStream);
```

Comment: A quick tip, if you are processing this in a Servlet, I imagine you are processing image uploads? If that is the case, I did something similar on imgscalr.com and pull the binary image data directly from the request body and streaming it into ImageIO decoding process via a Stream. It helps avoid writing out the file then reading it back in and decoding it. Another tip, if this is on EC2 and you are using an EBS volume, you might get better throughput using the volatile local disks on the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to answer my question, using java.awt.Toolkit to load images has solved the problem.

Comment: What do the timings look like now using Toolkit to load the images instead of ImageIO?

Comment: the whole process takes about 600ms now. I took also thumbnailator (http://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator) instead of imgscalr which is more performant and generates better images.