# Memory Efficient File/Image Upload in Java?

Tags: java, servlets, grails, grails-2.0

I want to upload images which are 2MB - 10MB to my server and save them directly to hard disk. The goal is to save as much Heap Memory of my JVM as I can, because if user upload concurrently my sysem should not crash.

This is how I do it at the moment. When a request with an upload come into my Controller I do:

```
CommonsMultipartFile file = (CommonsMultipartFile) request.getFile('image')
InputStream inputStream = file.inputStream
byte [] byteFile = inputStream.getBytes()

try{
  def fullPath = // some image path and file name
  def newFile = new FileOutputStream(fullPath)
  newFile.write(byteFile)
  newFile.close()
}
catch(IOException e){ }
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142069/scale-large-images-using-java-and-asyncscalr) I read that there is ImageIO and java.awt.Toolkit, where Toolkit is supposed to be the fastest to store the file.

How can I improve my upload to use as less heap as possible and upload as fast as possible?

Alternative 1:

An alternative could be to:

```
CommonsMultipartFile file = (CommonsMultipartFile) request.getFile('image')
def fullPath = // some image path and file name
file.transferTo(new File(fullPath))
```

Which one is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code receives an input stream with the file contents, but then buffers the whole contents of that stream in a `byte[]` before writing it out to a file on disk.  Your "alternative 1" streams directly to the from the input stream to the file on disk so will be much more memory-efficient and at least as fast as your current buffering approach (probably faster as there's less garbage to collect along the way).

Comment: Is my Alternative 1 the same as this: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html ? Is it as fast?

Comment: @stephan1001 using `transferTo` should always be the fastest way to do what you want.  Commons-fileupload buffers small uploads in memory and streams larger ones to temporary files on disk.  Calling `transferTo` will dump the buffer if the file is already buffered in memory, or rename the temporary file if it can, or do a streaming copy from the temporary file to the destination if it can't.  Letting the framework pick the most efficient approach for each file using its "insider knowledge" will never be slower than picking one approach yourself and using it unconditionally.

Comment: Is encoding something I have to take care of here? If so how can I ensure that the incomming file is encoded UTF-8?

Comment: @stephan1001 no, character encodings only apply to text data, images are pure binary data, and `transferTo` simply saves the uploaded bytes to a file without regard for what those bytes represent.

Comment: So I do not have to take care of encoding for bin files?

Comment: @stephan1001 no, character encodings only apply to text data...

Answer (score 0):

If you use the commons-fileupload lib and use it *in streaming mode* ([docs here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html)), you'll never have to hold any more of the incoming file in memory than you want to.  As the request comes in from the client and you iterate over each item, you get an InputStream for each form field or uploading file, and can do whatever you want with that InputStream, such as write it to a file (and including throwing an exception if a user has tried to upload, say, a 2GB file when your limit is 20MB or whatever).

The only disadvantage to using commons-fleupload's streaming API is that handling regular form fields must be done via an InputStream too, but that's easily done with a call to the lib's `Streams.asString()`.

Comment: Could you place the code for the commons-fileupload streaming? When I do file.inputStream isn't that what you mean? Also I updated my post is the second alternative better?